# git checkout projects with missing node_modules

Tags: angular, github

What are the steps to properly checkout a project that had node_modules in .gitignore?  I have 2 computers. What I've been doing is

1. From computer 1, git commit the project to GitHub
2. On computer 2, build a blank angular project with the same name and folder structure in order to create node_modules
3. On computer 2, clone the project from github into a different folder
4. On computer 2, copy the src folder from github version to the blank project

It seems to be defeating the purpose of github.  So how do I avoid this weird approach?  Is there an elegant way of cloning a project with missing dependencies (in this case node_modules)?  I must believe there is a simple solution, but I can't seem to google the right keywords to find the solution.  What keyword should I be using to find this solution?

Comment: you can skip 2 and 4. just `git clone` the project and `npm install` in the project folder to install the dependencies.

Comment: You should never commit `node_modules` to git. They should always be installed with `npm install` or `yarn install`.

Answer (score 2):

How [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-npm/) works is that there is a `package.json` file that lists the npm packages and versions for the project.  So when you clone the project, you get the `package.json` along with the source, sans the `node_modules` folder.  The first step you need to do is go to a command prompt and change to the directory with `package.json`.  Then type in `npm install`.  If you have node installed correctly and added to your path, this will look at the `package.json` file and download the packages from the internet, creating the `node_modules` folder.  You could install [yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn) as a replacement for npm by typing `npm install -g yarn`.  Then you type `yarn` instead of `npm install` to create the node_modules folder.

There is no need to recreate a project to create the node_modules folder, in fact that will probably cause issues because you won't have the same versions that are specified in the `package.json` of the repository you cloned.